# Polynomial regression interaction features

Tags: regression, interaction, scikit-learn, polynomial

In polynomial regression input vector $[a,b,c]$ is transformed into $[1, a, b, c, a^2, b^2, c^2, ab, ac, bc]$ before linear regression is applied. At least this is how `sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures` is doing it.

Why interaction features $a^2b, a^2c, b^2a, b^2c, c^2a, c^2b$ and $abc$ are not included?

Comment: Those would be third order interactions and `PolynomialFeatures` has set the default for `degree` to be 2.

Comment: @DemetriPananos Oh I see. It makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Demetri Pananos: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer?
[Better to have a short answer than no answer at
all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/)
Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Sure, will dp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the features you list are the product of 3 terms, hence they are third order interaction terms.

[According to the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html), the default degree computed for the `Polynomial` transformer is `degree=2`.  Additionally, if you only wanted those features and not the homogenous terms ($a^3, b^3, c^3$) you could set `interaction_only=True`.